# Java-threadPool - synchronize Threds

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

**edit:**  1.) Why is "globalCounter" synchronized , but not "Thread.currentThread().getId()"

2.) Can I assign a calculation to each thread? how? Can i work with the results?

```
public class Hauptprogramm {

public static final int MAX_THREADS = 10;
public static int globalCounter;
public static Integer syncObject = new Integer(0);


public static void main(String[] args) {


    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {

            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    synchronized (syncObject) {
                    globalCounter++;

                    System.out.println(globalCounter);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());


                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }

                                        }
                }});

        }

    threadPool.shutdown();

}
     }
```

Comment: Why bother with threads if they all synchronize on the same thing over all the work that is performed?

Comment: Can you clarify what language this is asking about?

Comment: @user2864740  i edit my question. Maybe its more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) Why is "globalCounter" synchronized , but not "Thread.currentThread().getId()"

I can answer why `globalCounter` is synchronized. To avoid data race and race condition.

In case if it is not synchronized - `globalCounter++` computation is a three step process (Read-Modify-Write) -

1. Read the current value of `globalCounter` varaible.
2. Modify its value.
3. Write/ Assign the modified value back to the `globalCounter`.

In the absence of `synchronization` in multi threaded environment, there is a possibility that a thread might read/ modifies the value of `globalCounter` when another thread is in the mid of this 3 step process.

This can result into thread/s reading stale values or loss of update count.

> 2) Can I assign a calculation to each thread? how? Can i work with the results?

This is possible. You can look into Future/ [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) to work with the result

Comment: I need callable and future, otherwise i cant synchronize the Thread ID? (I found a example where its working with callable and future)

Comment: We go for `Callable` if we are interested in the result returned by the execution of a task. `Future` defines the contract to retrieve that result. Not sure, what you meant by `can't synchronize the thread id`.

Comment: the outprint of globalCounter is "1,2,3..10" , but when i outprint the thread.id, the id is random. (17, 15, 11...).

Comment: Thread id is something which gets generated for us by the run time. We don't do any for it.